# PyGithub `Repository.compare(base, head)` not working

Tags: python, pygithub

I am trying to run a compare in out GitHub Enterprise Repo with PyGitHub. My Code looks like this:

```
repo = github.get_repo("my/repo")
log.debug(f"The Repo: {repo}")
log.debug(f"The URL: {repo.compare_url}")

labels = repo.get_labels()
log.debug(f"Labels: {labels.totalCount}")

compare = repo.compare("BRANCH_A", "TAG_B")
log.debug("Compare:\n{compare}")
```

As Result I get this:

```
2020-10-08:13:38:15,349 DEBUG    [changelog.py:50] The Repo: Repository(full_name="my/repo")
2020-10-08:13:38:15,349 DEBUG    [changelog.py:51] The URL: https://<my.enterprise-github.host>/api/v3/repos/my/repo/compare/{base}...{head}
2020-10-08:13:38:15,446 DEBUG    [changelog.py:54] Labels: 13
2020-10-08:13:38:16,114 DEBUG    [changelog.py:57] Compare:
{compare}
```

If I run the URL printed out in line 3 with correct Parameters (`https://<my.enterprise-github.host>/api/v3/repos/my/repo/compare/BRANCH_A...TAG_B`) with insomnia, I am getting the right result. Do you have any hints, why `Repository.compare` in PyGitHub is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This question is a result of my python-noob-level:

I forgot to format the Log-String, in which I wanted to show the Compare-Result:

```
log.debug(**f**"Compare:\n{compare}")
```